# Category Events

Tags: tournament

Will the candidates tournament 2013 (average of about **2785**) be the first `Category 22` event? If not can some one share the list of previous category 22 tournaments?

Reference:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELO_rating_system#FIDE_tournament_categories

Comment: The 2010 Bilbao Grand Slam Masters Final was a category 22 tournament (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbao_Chess_Masters_Final#Third_Grand_Slam_Masters_Final_.282010.29). Of course, it only had 4 participants, which makes it a lot easier to be high category. (BTW, I'm not sure that the 2008 edition was actually 22nd category as the answer below says. The crosstable at that link at least yields an average rating of 2769, a bit shy of the mark.) I'd guess that some of the most recent Tal Memorials might have been 22nd category as well; a look at old rating lists can say whether or not that's so.

Comment: Does it need to have a minimum number of participants? otherwise most WC matches will qualify for cat 22

Comment: Strange, some places list it the 2008 as a category 22 event and some others don't. I even find places where they say there has never been one, so things are out of order somewhere.  Does anyone know if FIDE amended the category ratings?

Answer (score 4):

`Bilbao Masters in 2008 was a category 22 event`

Comment: according to this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbao_Chess_Masters_Final averaged 2768/69